# Jasmine test returns type error when using $httpBackend.flush();

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm having an issue when I run a jasmine unit test with  $httpBackend backend mock. I'm wanting to test the value returned from a service call. It's calling the service and hitting the end point but I keep getting an error from the method itself. Not sure what I'm missing in order for this to work. Any help is really appreciated.

//error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data[0].data')
```

///unit test

```
  describe("DataService", function () {

        describe('testing service', function() {
            var TheService, scope;

            beforeEach(function () {
                module(moduleName);
                module('services');
            });

            beforeEach(inject(function($injector,$rootScope) {
                TheService = $injector.get('TheService');
                scope=$rootScope.$new();
            }));

            it('should have a method defined', function() {
                expect(TheService.getStuff).toBeDefined();
            });

            it('should have a method defined', inject(function($httpBackend) {

            var mock = { data: 'World' };


                $httpBackend.whenGET("/theurl/getStuff").respond({ data: 'World' });


                $httpBackend.expectGET("/theurl/getStuff");

                TheService.getStuff();

                scope.$digest();

                expect(TheService.getStuff).toEqual(mock);

                $httpBackend.flush();
            }));

        });

});
```

//service method

```
   function TheService($http, $q) {
        var vm = this;


        vm.getStuffs = null;
        vm.getStuff = getStuff;
        vm.theresponse = {};

        function getStuff() {

           var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "/theurl/getStuff"

            }).success(function(data){

               vm.theresponse = data[0].data
                deferred.resolve(vm.theresponse);

            }).error(function(){

                deferred.reject('An error occurred');

            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the fake endpoint returns

```
{ data: 'World' }
```

But the service tries to access

```
data[0].data
```

data is an object. It's not an array. So `data[0]` is undefined.

For the service code to work fine, you should return something like

```
[{ data: 'World' }]
```

Also, your code uses a promise antipattern, and deprecated success and error callbacks. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/ for a better alternative: